# how to access variable from .getCurrentPosition() function javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the code and i want for example to access the latitude variable outside of this function and for example set  to its value.

```
var latitude = "b";

var longitude = "c";


navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showLocation(position) {

    latitude = position.coords.latitude;

    longitude = position.coords.longitude; 

});

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation(position);

$(".test").html(latitude)
```

Comment: You're missing parentheses on the line `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation(position);`. Also, that line doesn't make any sense at all. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: I need to access var latitude and set <div class= "test"> to its value

Comment: Then delete that line, the `longitude` variable, and the line that assigns to it

Comment: But I need to access the overwrited value, not just "b". And that overwrited value should be my current latitude.

Comment: No the LONGITUDE var (if you're not going to use it)

Comment: Ah, the longitude, but i need to use it as well, this is just example. I just need to somehow access the value of those 2 variables outside of this .getCurrentPosition() function.

Comment: Okay then just delete the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation(position);` line

Comment: I tried, but it sets <div class = "test"> to value of "b" then, not to my current latitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly pretty, but this should work:

```
var latitude;
var longitude;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showLocation(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    continueExecution();                             // or something similar
});

function continueExecution() {
    $(".test").html(latitude)
    ...                                              // blah blah blah
}
```

NOTE: Some browsers disable geolocation to non-HTTPS websites because of obvious reasons. Check to make sure your browser isn't blocking the geolocation.

ANOTHER NOTE: Because of the asynchronous nature of the `getCurrentPosition` call, you must make sure the function inside `getCurrentPosition` has run before you check the values of `longitude` and `latitude`.

Comment: What error did you get? I think it has to do with either codepen.io or your browser not supporting `navigator.geolocation`

Comment: I can for example set <div class = "test"> to my current latitude INSIDE the function and it works on codepen.io. But outside of the function not. And I really need to use that value from outside of the function because ill need it in $.getJSON then...

Comment: @AlexanderTaran It doesn't work for codepen.io because it doesn't use JQuery by default

Comment: Also, I just made a Codepen.io account and my point in my answer still stands. It doesn't run because your browser doesn't allow it to run for security reasons

Comment: I added https:// to to the link and it works, but as I said only inside this .getCurrentPosition function... Do you have any idea how to access it outside of the function on codepen.io? :D But now I at least know that its an codepen issue.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran I don't think you can. Of course, you can just call it once and store the value outside the function, like you have here. But you can only access it from the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function because the browsers need to be able to disable it

Comment: So for example if i have this link: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon} and I want to use it in $.getJSON but i need to set {lat} and {lon} to my current lat and lon, what should I do? :D Btw I cant use $.getJSON in that navigator function cuz it doesnt work (even if I set it to async: false)...

Comment: @AlexanderTaran Yes, that's a good point. See my new edit. Tell me if that helps

Comment: $.getJSON is still not working, even inside this new function... :( So I think that the main question is: How to set variable to my current latitude outside the .getCurrentLocation function? :D

Comment: So, after a million attempts, I created a function that can both acces the variables and make an json call. But, json call is not working with that variables :D So for example if I declare an var ulr using latitude and longitude, $.getJSON just wont make call using this var ulr :D Ill try to somehow solve it.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran `$.getJSON` is also asynchronous, so you'll have to use tactics similar to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` (i.e. wait until `$.getJSON` has run)

Answer (score -1):

First of all your question is not clear enough and your code creates more confusion. From best of my understanding, I assume you want to get latitude value returned from the function and printed in `<div>` tag.  Check out below snippet. Is it this what you wanted?

```js
var position = {
   coords : {
      latitude: "b",
      longitude: "c"
   }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 var location = showLocation(position);
 $(".test").html(location.lat);
});

function showLocation(position) {

var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude; 

return {
lat: latitude,
lon: longitude
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Latitude goes here...</div>
```

Comment: Latitude should be my current latitude, not "b". So in <div class = "test"> should be printed my current latitude.